# Two Stun servers (coturn) with the same IP but different port

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I'm trying to determine the mapping behaviour of a NAT using two STUN servers. I need two stun servers with the same IP but different port.
I was wondering if it's possible to set up **two** coturn stun servers on the same host.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your host as two or more valid IP addresses. In the examples below, let's assume the host has two public IP addresses: `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5`.

[stuntman](https://www.stunprotocol.org/) has this option to bind to multiple IP addresses if offered by the same host.

```
stunserver --mode full --primaryinterface 1.2.3.4 --altinterface 1.2.3.5
```

And if running in a NAT'd environment with port forwarding (such as AWS), you can specify the IP mappings such that the `CHANGED_ADDRESS` or (`OTHER_ADDRESS`) will be correct when it responds to STUN binding requests.  Example:

```
stunserver --mode full --primaryinterface 10.0.0.4 --altinterface 10.0.0.5 --primaryadvertised 1.2.3.4 --altadvertised 1.2.3.5
```

Where 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.5 are the private LAN ip addresses of the host.

[coturn](https://www.mankier.com/1/turnserver) appears to have the same option with the `-L` and `-X` options

```
turnserver -L 1.2.3.4 -L 1.2.3.5
```

With the `-X` option used to specify the advertised address in a NAT scenario.

Comment: sorry if I'm not correct, I'm still trying to understand how this works, by using `turnserver -L 1.2.3.4 -L 1.2.3.5` you are configuring two listening IP's to the same STUN server and using the default port 3478. But what I want to do is use the same IP and have two different ports. Would it work if I use the following configuration:   `listening-port=3478` 
`alt-listening-port=3000` ?  Thanks in advance!